# Trying to put my pygame surface into a class

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, nameerror

I'm attempting to start using classes and OOP for a lot in my programming, and am trying to setup my basic game window into a display class, which when called creates the game window, and does all of the pygame initilization.

I've completed a view tutorials, but am having a hard time finding one that encapsulates the pygame.display calls into a class. Is this because this /should not/ be done for pygame to work properly?

The most common errors I've gotten while playing around with it are

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 27, in Display
NameError: name 'Display' is not defined
```

If I modify my code(by replacing class Display(object):  -- > class Display(width, height, tilesize), which are the values I am trying to pass in I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'width' is not defined
```

Just trying to figure out if the error is in my syntax, or if I am trying to attempt the impossible.
Thanks :)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#Constants
TILESIZE = 32
MAPWIDTH = 16
MAPHEIGHT = 16

#variables
playing = True

#Creates Display Window
class Display(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height, tilesize):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_icon("player.jpg")
        pygame.display.set_caption("FarmTown Version 1.0")
        self.SCREEN_WIDTH = width * tilesize
        self.SCREEN_HEIGHT = height * tilesize
        self.myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])

    def update():
        pygame.display.flip()

#Set Up Everything To Play
    myDisplay = Display(MAPWIDTH, MAPHEIGHT, TILESIZE)


#Game Loop Begins
while playing:
    #Display the surface
    myDisplay.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myDisplay is indented, so python thinks it is a part of the Display class.  You can't create an instance of a class within the definition of that class.  Also, set_icon expects a pygame Surface object, not a path to a file.  To fix that, do this:

```
    # ...
    icon = pygame.image.load("player.jpg")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    # ...
```

Finally, you should change this:

```
self.myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
```

to this:

```
self.myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([self.SCREEN_WIDTH, self.SCREEN_HEIGHT])
```

Comment: What a great reminder that even though identing makes the code pretty, I can't do that in python. Thanks for the extra tip on the icon part. I fixed the last portion once I cleared the error message, before I saw that portion. Thanks for giving such a thorough answer. I love when bug fixes are simple. Thanks again.